# pyreadr not working (how to import RData file to python)

Tags: python, r

I always get an empty dictionary when I import any RData file into Python using pyreadr. Here is my Python code:

```
import pyreadr

result = pyreadr.read_r('data.RData')
print(result.keys())
```

which returns

```
odict_keys([])
```

I have pyreadr installed and am running Python version 3.7.11 on Mac. In the above example I generated the RData file 'data.RData' in RStudio as follows:

```
x <- c(0.20,0.30,0.27,0.23)
data <- list("a", 5.1, x)
save(data, file="data.RData")
```

I'm sure 'data.RData' is in the right directory. What's going wrong?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr): "Lists and S4 objects are not supported".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is going wrong: lists are not supported by pyreadr.

See the documentation section [What objects can be read and written](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr#what-objects-can-be-read-and-written).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `rdata` instead. It allows lists and S4 objects, and it is written in pure Python (so you can easily install it everywhere):

```py
import rdata

parsed = rdata.parser.parse_file("data.RData")
converted = rdata.conversion.convert(parsed)
print(converted)
```

```
{'data': [['a'], array([5.1]), array([0.2 , 0.3 , 0.27, 0.23])]}
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the `rdata` package.